# How do I override functions in this class?

Tags: python, pygal

I am using the pygal library to create charts and want to override a few of the functions, such as the _tooltip_data function, among others. For starters, I am trying to override the _title function (To create the text, I realize I can do: gauge.title = "Blah Title", but I want to override some other things in the _title function).

I'm pretty lost. To create a Gauge chart, I create a Gauge class, which inherets from MyGraph class, which inherets from pypal's Graph class. If I try to create a MyGauge chart, then I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MyGauge'
```

Here's my code, complete with what I'm sure are a ton of errors. Keep in mind that I'm still a newb (I probably didn't have to tell you that, you could probably guess that just by looking at my code).

```
import pygal, os 
from pygal.graph.graph import Graph
from pygal.graph.gauge import Gauge
from pygal.graph import CHARTS_NAMES

class MyGraph(Graph):

    def _title(self):
        """Make the title"""
        if self.title:
            for i, title_line in enumerate(self.title, 1):
                self.svg.node(
                    self.nodes['graph'], 'text', class_='title',
                    x=self.margin.left + self.view.width / 2,
                    y=i * (self.title_font_size + 10)
                ).text = "Hey, this is my Chart Title" # my addition

class MyGauge(MyGraph):
    pass


gauge_chart = pygal.MyGauge(human_readable=True,pretty_print=True) #@UndefinedVariable
gauge_chart.title = 'DeltaBlue V8 benchmark results'
gauge_chart.x_labels = ['Richards', 'DeltaBlue', 'Crypto', 'RayTrace', 'EarleyBoyer', 'RegExp', 'Splay', 'NavierStokes']
gauge_chart.range = [0, 10000]
gauge_chart.add('Chrome', 8212)
gauge_chart.add('Firefox', 8099)
gauge_chart.add('Opera', 2933)
gauge_chart.add('IE', 41)


png = 'gauge.png'
if os.path.isfile(png):
    os.remove(png)

gauge_chart.render_to_png(png)
```

I'm stuck. I even tried to create a MyPygal class, which inherets from pygal, so I could override the CHARTS_NAMES

```
class MyPygal(pygal):
    def __init__(self):
        CHARTS_NAMES = [
            'Line',
            'StackedLine',
            'XY',
            'Bar',
            'HorizontalBar',
            'StackedBar',
            'HorizontalStackedBar',
            'Pie',
            'Radar',
            'Funnel',
            'Pyramid',
            'VerticalPyramid',
            'Dot',
            'Gauge',
            'MyGauge' # my new chart type
        ]
```

Which I call with "MyPygal.MyGauge" but with that I get the error:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Am I even on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create your own class in your own file, don't try to refer to it with `pygal.MyGauge`.  Using the `pygal.` prefix is for referring to things inside the `pygal` library.  But your `MyGauge` class isn't part of that library; you created it yourself.  Just instantiate your class with `MyGauge(...)`.

Also, why did you create the `MyGauge` class at all?  It doesn't do anything.  Why not just instantiate `MyGraph` directly?

Comment: Since pygal's Gauge class inherits from their Graph class, I thought MyGauge had to inherit from MyGraph so that the MyGauge charts would be based off MyGraph, no?

Comment: @Mr.Gaga: The question is what you want `MyGauge` to do that `MyGraph` doesn't already do.  The way you have it now, `MyGauge` provides no functionality of its own; it's just a superfluous wrapper around `MyGraph`.  Presumably in `pygal` the `Gauge` class adds something to the `Graph` class, which is why there are two classes.  But there's no need to create two classes if you only have one class's worth of customizations to do.  The names of the classes don't mean anything; what matters is the code inside the classes.

Comment: oh, ok. Where do I go from here, then?

Comment: @Mr.Gaga: I don't know, since I'm not familiar with `pygal` and I don't really know what you're trying to do.  If what I suggested fixed the error, then you should just continue to develop your class until it does what you want, whatever that is.

Comment: Thanks anyway, but I'm still confused on how to call my new class

Comment: @Mr.Gaga: Like I said, right where you have `pygal.MyGauge(human_readable=True,pretty_print=True)`, change it to `MyGauge(human_readable=True,pretty_print=True)`.

Comment: I get an error "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'human_readable'"

Comment: @Mr.Gaga: Okay, but that's progress anyway, because at least you're getting an error that has to do with how you actually defined your class.  It might be time to ask another question about that error.  Is `human_readable` something that `pygal.Graph` already accepts and knows about?  If not, you need to define it on your class.  I would suggest you try some simpler exercises, just creating a few classes that inherit from each other, to get a feel for how to do class inheritance in Python, before you try extending classes from existing libraries.